# matlab: what is the command-line equivalent of 'copy figure'?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, adobe-illustrator

If I use `print -clipboard -dmeta` I get a different result (non-vectorized when pasting into Illustrator) than when I literally click 'copy figure' in the figure window.

1. Does anyone know what happens when you click 'copy figure' in the figure menu ('under the hood'?)
2. Is there a matlab function that would mimic this function more precisely than
    `print -clipboard -dmeta`?

ver output:

```
MATLAB Version: 9.9.0.1524771 (R2020b) Update 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems, something is not correct, because the command `print -clipboard -dmeta` copy the figure as *vector data*

Anyway you can alternatively save as the current figure with **Enhanced metafile** extension:  `saveas(gcf, 'Fig1.emf')`, then load the vector-based file into any software.

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
print -clipboard -dmeta
```

and

```
hgexport(gcf, '-clipboard')
```

will export the current figure as a Windows metafile if:

1. You’re on a Windows platform.
2. The figure uses the Painters renderer.

When using the OpenGL renderer, exports are always as a bitmap.

To switch a figure to use the Painters renderer, use

```
set(gcf,'renderer','painters');
```